# Is there a good way to manage javascript dependencies provided by a CDN?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework-2.0, cdn, dependency-management

I want to use http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com as much as possible for javascript dependencies. But from a development perspective two things about this bother me. The first is minor: there's a lot of copy pasting and it looks ugly and filled with redundancy:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/0.20.0/quill.min.js"></script>
...etc.
```

Secondly I'm worried about nested dependencies. For every library I reference like this I have to make sure that any dependencies it has are also provided, which means:

- Finding out what the dependencies are (there might not be any but I need to verify that)
- Adding more tags for them
- Repeating the process for these dependencies themselves
- Managing versions for each library
- Keeping them in the correct order

I then also have to combine this with whatever methods I have for managing my own code and libraries that aren't available on cdnjs which might make things fragmented and more confusing.

If I serve the dependencies myself then there are tools like npm, bower, and grunt. Is there a similarly robust and easy way to manage externally hosted dependencies?

I'm using the Play Framework with Scala and ScalaJS, but I'm interested in solutions for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered perhaps using WebJars to pull in the dependencies into your project (and thus their dependencies)?

Then, you can have CloudFlare (the same CDN) proxy your site's assets, which would be the same-ish.

Comment: If you mean pay for custom CDN hosting, I'm aiming for the free solution.

Comment: No, CloudFlare has a free plan. It caches your assets on first request and serves them on your behalf through its CDN network. For details, see https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn

Comment: Oh wow, I did a brief search but I guess I assumed that free quality custom hosting was too good to be true and didn't check properly. Thanks for that.